# php phalcon micro api endpoint return 404 except root url

Tags: php, devops, apache2, phalcon, phalcon-routing

I am trying to setup very simple, 2 api endpoints using **Php Phalcon Micro**. I am getting 404 not found on endpoint route with "/api/healthcheck". But when I call root "/", I get proper response. I request to guide me on this issue. Thanking you in advance.

**System architecture:** Ec2 Server is under vpc and public subnet. Ubuntu: 22.04, PHP: 5.6, Apache 2.4.52

**Request flow:** domain.com -> nginx : 80 -> apache2 virtualhost : 8081 -> project folder with .htaccess

Api endpoint 1st:

```
 Request: domain.com/
 Response: status 200
      Array{
        "id": "1",
        "version": "1"
      }
```

Api endpoint 2nd:

```
 Request: domain.com/api/healthcheck
 Response: status 404 not found
```

.htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^((?s).*)$ index.php?_url=/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

/var/www/domain.com/index.php

```
<?php
// Phalcon
use Phalcon\Loader;
use Phalcon\Mvc\Micro;
use Phalcon\Di\FactoryDefault;
use Phalcon\Db\Adapter\Pdo\Mysql as PdoMysql;

use Phalcon\Http\Response;
use Phalcon\Http\Request;

// Getting a request instance
$request = new Request();

// Set up Database Service
$di = new FactoryDefault();

// Set up the database service
$di->set('db', function () {
    return new PdoMysql(
        array(
            "host"     => DB_SERVER,
            "username" => DB_USER,
            "password" => DB_PASS,
            "dbname"   => DB_NAME
        )
    );
});

$app = new Micro($di);

$app->get(
    '/',
    function () use ($dbConn) {
        $sql = 'SELECT * FROM `dbversions` WHERE 1 Order By id desc LIMIT 1';
        $result_set = mysqli_query($dbConn, $sql);
        $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set);
        echo json_encode($row);
    }
);

$app->get(
    '/api/healthcheck',
    function () use ($dbConn) {
        $data = array("status"=> "success");
        echo json_encode($data);
    }
);

$app->handle();
?>
```

Apache2: /etc/apache2/apache.conf

```
<Directory />
        Options FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all denied
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share>
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/>
        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride None
        Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Virtual Host: /etc/apache2/site-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:8081>
    ServerName domain.com
    ServerAdmin webmaster@domain.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/domain.com/

    <Directory /var/www/domain.com>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Php8.1 Packages: sudo dpkg -l | awk '/^ii/{print $2}' | grep php8.1 | tee php8.1-packages.tx

```
libapache2-mod-php8.1
php8.1
php8.1-cli
php8.1-common
php8.1-curl
php8.1-dev
php8.1-fpm
php8.1-mbstring
php8.1-mysql
php8.1-opcache
php8.1-phalcon5
php8.1-readline
```

Php5.6 Packages: sudo dpkg -l | awk '/^ii/{print $2}' | grep php5.6 | tee php5.6-packages.tx

```
libapache2-mod-php5.6
php5.6
php5.6-cli
php5.6-common
php5.6-curl
php5.6-dev
php5.6-fpm
php5.6-json
php5.6-mbstring
php5.6-mysql
php5.6-opcache
php5.6-phalcon3
php5.6-readline
```

Nginx Access Logs: sudo tail -f /var/log/nginx/access.log

```
100.250.01.01 - - [26/Oct/2023:01:38:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 85 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.33.0"
100.250.01.01 - - [26/Oct/2023:01:38:23 +0000] "GET /api/healthcheck HTTP/1.1" 404 240 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.33.0"
```

Apcahe2 Access Logs: sudo tail -f /var/log/apache2/access.log

```
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Oct/2023:01:38:12 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.0" 200 299 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.33.0"
127.0.0.1 - - [26/Oct/2023:01:38:23 +0000] "GET /api/healthcheck HTTP/1.0" 404 450 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.33.0"
```

Comment: `/api/healthcheck` or `/api/healthcheck/`? (PHP5.6 died ~5 years ago)

Comment: @brombeer I think issue is with access..may be not with php. but still let me try with php7.* or php8.*. Also issue is not becuz of /api/healthcheck, typo mistake.

Comment: I think the issue is with your route being declared _with_ trailing slash while you access the route _without_ the trailing slash. Try using `'/api/healthcheck',` in your route declaration

Comment: I have change php to 8.1 but still have same issue. @brombeer

Comment: If you are using php 7.* you have to install Phalcon 4; for php 8 go for Phalcon 5. And there will be differences on the API configuration.

Comment: @Arthur I have changed the phalcon version based on php.

Comment: @brombeer also tried with '/api/healthcheck'..not working..I have updated and added more details in description about php packages installed, config of virtual host and apache config file like apache2.conf, envvars, ports.conf

Comment: There are many issues to address in your code because it is not using the full power of Phalcon Micro. In example, with the dependency injection container you don't have to make database calls with `myslqi` or use `json_encode` to return your responses. Check https://docs.phalcon.io/5.0/en/application-micro and  https://docs.phalcon.io/5.0/en/tutorial-rest

Comment: @Arthur the issue is..not able to call /api/healthcheck endpoint..I get 404..if I dont use anything, which is mysqli or json_encode..still get 404 not found

Comment: Try to use `$app->handle(
    $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]
);`  Also, try replacing 'domain.com' for 'domain.dev', then you skip DNS problems as well.